# Maven shaded uber-jar: Jar throws exception if build on one particular system

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have a java maven project which I pack with maven-shaded as standalone runnable fat-jar. 
If I create the jar on my MacBook Pro it fails after some time (iMac and Linux).
If I create the jar on my iMac it runs flawless on any system

I am unaware of any differences between my two systems. Both java 8, Eclipse Luna, same project and pom configuration. 
I noticed some time ago that the size of the jars differs too depending on which system it was build which probably should also not be the case, right?

I originally started debugging like crazy what is wrong with my code, but could/still can't find anything. I am wondering if this might be some maven problem? The fact that it runs if compiled on the iMac gives me at least a certain confidence that it is not a classical program bug.

Has anyone made similar observations or has a hint for me what the cause of the problem could be?

Comment: You should try to create a minimal example that reproduces the problem and come back here with the code. It is very hard to tell what might be wrong without being able to reproduce it.

Comment: First. Using the same Maven version. Are all plugins correctly defined with their versions? Are you trying to build in Eclipse or on command line ?